# ERROR INSTALL on LAPTOP MSI GE60 2PL APACHE

Tags: system-installation

[image]

I tried to install with version 18.04, 16.04 and 14.04, but it doesn't work because of an uncomprehensive dialog showing `??? ???`.

Comment: Have you tried disabling secure boot from uefi?